# Alignment for 2nd row data

Tags: css

```
<table>
    <tr><td>test</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style= height:200px;">
                <div  style="border:1px solid yellow; display: inline-block; width:100px">
                    <img src="orderedList4.png">
                </div>
                <div align="center" style="border:1px solid green;  display: inline-block; width:650px;height:100px;">
                    <div>center Test Header1</div>
                    <div>center Test Header2</div>
                </div>
                <div align="right" style="border:1px solid red;display: inline-block; width:100px">REL 1.0</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the above code, the image size is 75*75 pixels.

1. I want to have all the three cells to have a height of 100 pixels.
2. I want the image to be centered and left aligned.
3. The middle text to centered.
4. Third text to centered and right aligned.

I could not make it working.

Comment: Tried chnaging the height properties of differnet div tags. etc. No results yet.

Comment: Confusing post is confusing. And uses tables.

Comment: Would you like a beverage with that?

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles are a nightmare to maintain, and you should generally be trying to keep presentation separate from the content. I've moved all the styles out of the actual tags, and since you're using a table and refer to each `div` as a cell, I'm guessing you meant to have each one an *actual* cell.

```
<style>
.product_table {
    width:  850px;
}
    .product_table td {
        height:         100px;
        border:         solid 1px #000;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
        .product_table .image {
            width:      100px;
            border-color:   yellow;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .product_table .title {
            /* Automatically sizes its width */
            border-color:   green;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .product_table .release {
            width:      100px;
            border-color:   red;
            text-align: right;
        }
</style>

<table class="product_table">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">test</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="image">
            <img src="orderedList4.png" />
        </td>
        <td class="title">
            <div>center Test Header1</div>
            <div>center Test Header2</div>
        </td>
        <td class="release">
            REL 1.0
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The top row is probably a table heading though, so you should consider moving that out of the table as a `h2` or whatever level it'll be used in. And make sure a table is the most appropriate element here – unless you're going to have multiple rows of whatever this item is, you might be better off just using `div`s without tables.